# momentjs moment() function makes the UI freeze while lazy loading in angular2

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, momentjs

I am trying to show a "loading..." text in Angular2 while loading the lazy routes but the strange thing is that as soon as I use moment() function from momentjs the UI is frozen during the lazy loading causing the "loading..." not to show until the navigation is finished.

I'm using the code below to show and hide the "loading..." text:

```
router.events.subscribe(ev => {
  if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) 
  { 
    console.log("Navigation started");
    this.isNavigating = true; 

  }
  if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd || ev instanceof NavigationError || ev instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    console.log("Navigation ended");
    this.isNavigating = false; }
  })
```

Here is the plunk that to demonstrate the issue but unfortunately I I don't know how to use momentjs in this plunker to demonstrate the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nXJE24ilpE9SS68kgQbG?p=preview

This is what I'm planning to do and this plunk works fine but as soon as I use moment() function (anywhere) the UI freezes during the load process.

I really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: It will help if you can show the code you're using to call moment, and where.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem, to fix, I just used momentjs by linking to the momentjs library instead of using it through NPM install and it fixed the issue. That simple but took me some time to figure out.
Here is some simple typing.d.ts:

```
declare function moment(): any; declare function moment(date): any;
declare namespace moment { class Moment {
}
function locale(string): any;
}
```

Hope you enjoy!